# chrome app webview error

Tags: angularjs, webview, google-chrome-app

I am building chrome app using angularjs 1.4. I use different tabs to switch to different urls and load them in webview by using webview.reload() which sets its src. eg :

```
 <div ng-init="view.init()"> 
    <webview src="" style="width: 100%;height: 750px;" id="webviewTab" partition="trusted"></webview>
```

When i do this the respective tab url is fired properly, however, it again redirects me back to the previous page and i get the below error in console :

```
  <webview>: The load has aborted with error -3: ERR_ABORTED.
   showWarningMessage   @   extensions::webViewEvents:237
   WebViewEvents.handleLoadAbortEvent   @   extensions::webViewEvents:242
   (anonymous)  @   extensions::guestViewEvents:97
   (anonymous)  @   extensions::guestViewEvents:169
   EventImpl.dispatchToListener @   extensions::event_bindings:388
   publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function)    @   extensions::utils:149
   EventImpl.dispatch_  @   extensions::event_bindings:372
   dispatchArgs @   extensions::event_bindings:244
   dispatchEvent    @   extensions::event_bindings:253
```

I use ng-init="view.init()" to initialize some variables, and in that i am initializing initial tab url.

Can anyone share your views. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found that passing true inside webview.reload(true) solves the issue, However i dont understand that what difference 'true' makes here